# How to declare array in post method with validation

Tags: node.js, express

In my project, I want to validate the missing fields during post method. Fields in my table look like:

```
{
  name: string, required: true
  products: [
    {
      name: string, required: true
      quantity: number, required: true
      rate: number
    }
  ]
```

Now I declare validation for the name field as follows:

```
req.checkBody('name','Missing params').notEmpty();
```

It works properly, but the array is not working and the code is:

```
req.checkBody(products: 'name','Missing params').notEmpty();         
req.checkBody(products: 'quantity','Missing params').notEmpty();
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to validate [an array in a nested object](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#nested-input-data), you have to pass an array. Instead of doing this:

```
req.checkBody(products: 'name','Missing params').notEmpty();
req.checkBody(products: 'name','Missing params').notEmpty();
```

, you should do this:

```
req.checkBody(['products', 0, 'name'],'Missing params').notEmpty();
req.checkBody(['products', 0, 'quantity'],'Must be an integer').isInt();
```

, and so on.

Comment: @AntonyMithun Sorry for the delay. In my first answer, i didn't realize it was an array inside the nested object. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thank you its work using "req.checkBody(['products', 0, 'name'],'Missing params').notEmpty();" Thanks